# Conditional Item Display based on Tab Selection in PowerApp Gallery

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, conditional, tags

Per this brilliant instructional video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1o2L0DADzKQ by Reza Dorrani I created collection colTabs to display different SharePoint List items in a PowerApps gallery. The OnStart property for App is this collection colTabs (smaller portion shown here):

```
ClearCollect(
colTabs,
{
    ID: 1,
    Name: "All States",
},
{
    ID: 2,
    Name: "East Coast",
},
{
    ID: 3,
    Name: "West Coast",
}
```

);

The "Name" from above are choice values from a SharePoint List regionsUSA.

So far in the main gallery I have the Items property as:

```
If(varTabSelected = 1, regionsUSA)
```

...and that is working fine displaying all items in the first tab. How do I expand the above If statement so that from the same SP List, if varTabSelected = 2, then only East Coast items are displayed, if varTabSelected = 3 only West Coast items are displayed and so on? Somehow I am having trouble pulling the choice items from the List so I am stuck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tabs are all based off the value in one choice column, this could be done a little bit simpler than what is in the video.

1. Change your `colTabs` collection to this:

> ClearCollect(
> colTabs,
> Choices(regionsUSA.ChoiceColumnName).Value )

(Update the `ChoiceColumnName` as appropriate)

2. For your Tab gallery, set the items property to `colTabs`
3. Set the OnSelect property of the gallery to `Set(varTabSelected, ThisItem.Value)`
4. For your Main gallery, set the items property to

> Filter(regionsUSA,ChoiceColumnName.Value = varTabSelected)

(Update the `ChoiceColumnName` as appropriate)